# An inequality about the sum of squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x_1,...,x_m$ be non-negative real numbers. Is the following inequality correct?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}x_n^2\geq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{n}{2^n}x_n\right)^2.$$

Comment: This sounds like a job for the QM-AM inequality.

Answer (score 5):

It is true. Using Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{n}{2^n}x_n\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{n^2}{4^n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^mx_n^2\right)$$

and we can prove that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{n^2}{4^n}=\frac{5\cdot 4^{m+1}-9m^2-24m-20}{27\cdot 4^m} < 1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer